# Correct way to add image from JSON file using Ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, json

I'm having difficulty getting an image to display using ajax. Not sure if I'm doing it correctly, nor can I find an example of what I'm trying to do. I can get the data to display, and I did wrap it in an  tag. All of the info displays ok, but the image. Here is my code.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $.getJSON("team.json", function(data) {
            $.each(data, function() {
                $.each(this, function(key, value) {
                    $("#team").append("<img src="value.image" />" +
                        "<h3>" + value.full_name + "</h3>" + "<h3>" +
                        value.title + "</h3>" +
                        value.tag_line + "<br>"
                    );
                });
            }); 
        });
    });
```

Comment: Positive the image source is the correct path?

Comment: are you missing some `+`s and escapes or alternate quotes? 

`"<img src='"+value.image+"'..`

Comment: Thanks Matt! After adding the +'s in <img src=" + value.image + " /> it works.

Answer (score 0):

you should either escape the quotation marks in `src=` or use single quotes.

Answer (score 0):

You have to escape the quotes:

```
"<img src=\"" + value.image + "\" />";
```

Or use single quotes like this:

```
'<img src="' + value.image + '" />';
```

Answer (score 0):

Escape the `"` like this

`$("#team").append("<img src=\"" + value.image + "\" />"`

or use `'` like this

```
$("#team").append("<img src='" + value.image + "' />"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
append("<img src="value.image" />" +
```

should be (if value.image is a base64 string)

```
append('<img src="data:image/jpg;base64,'+value.image+'" />'+
```

otherwise you are just using the wrong quotes

```
append('<img src="'+value.image+'" />' +
```